# Tips for rails blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for some blog that talks about ruby and rails.

Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also PlanetRubyOnRails:

http://www.planetrubyonrails.com/

which is an aggregator of many ruby (and ruby on rails) blogs ([you can find the list here](http://www.planetrubyonrails.com/pages/channels), and eventually select just those you like and add them to your own feed reader)

Answer (score 1):

I think that [Ryan's Scraps](http://ryandaigle.com/) is a very useful rails blog.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.rubyinside.com/
http://www.railsinside.com/

Both are good at summing interesting stuff up, got most of the people I follow on a regular basis from there. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) - free RoR screencasts.

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby Best Practices](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/) has lots of good general ruby advice, while [Yehuda Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/) seems able to not only be extremely productive developing bundler, rails 3 and more, but also write good articles about them.

Other blogs I read not already mentioned include [Ryan Tomayko](http://tomayko.com/), [Pratik Naik](http://m.onkey.org/) and [Pivotal Blabs](http://pivotallabs.com/blabs), not to mention [my own small corner of the web](http://tomafro.net).